# Backgroundworker gives multiple error messages

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a form with three textboxes in it. In my `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` handler I test if any `TextBox` is empty and launch a `MessageBox` asking the user to fill in all the `TextBox`es. This is done in a `Try/Catch` block. My problem is two fold. If the `TextBox`es aren't filled in the user gets the first `MessageBox` and then another `MessageBox` when the `Catch` exception is thrown...so this would be the second `MessageBox` the user gets. In my `BackGroundWorker1_RunWorkCompleted` handler I test if an `Exception` is thrown. It never acknowledges the error and immediately executes the `Else` block which will be the third message box the user receives saying "Process complete." The Process Complete should not have been shown.

How do I test if there are any `TextBox`es not filled in and if they're not throw 1 `MessageBox` telling the user to fill in all the `TextBox`es? And make my `RunWorkerComplete` handler acknowledge the `ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing`.

Thank you for your help.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    Try

        For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls()
            If TypeOf cntrl Is TextBox Then
                If CType(cntrl, TextBox).Text.Equals(String.Empty) Or (CType(cntrl, TextBox).Text = "") Then
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter value in all fields on form" & cntrl.Name.ToString())
                    cntrl.Focus()
                End If
            End If
        Next

        runProgram()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured while trying to load this application. Please contact Maxine Hammett for assistance " &
        vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MsgBox(" Operation Cancelled ")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Error in RunWorkerComplete" & e.Error.Message)
    Else
        MsgBox(" Process Complete ")
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Moved the control checking to the execute button. But now I get errors about the text boxes not having a path (one of the text boxes is a path to folder).

```
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Dim launchProgram As Boolean = False

    While launchProgram = False
        For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls()
            If TypeOf cntrl Is TextBox Then
                If CType(cntrl, TextBox).Text.Equals(String.Empty) Or (CType(cntrl, TextBox).Text = "") Then
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter value in all fields on form" & cntrl.Name.ToString())
                    cntrl.Focus()
                    launchProgram = False
                Else
                    launchProgram = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End While

    If launchProgram = True Then
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Multiple problems.  Do not use Try/Catch in DoWork(), it prevents RunWorkerCompleted from seeing the error.  Do not call MessageBox.Show() on a worker thread, there is no guarantee that the user can see it.  Do not do anything with the controls in DoWork(), they are not thread-safe and generate arbitrary exceptions.  These tests need to be done in the code that calls RunWorkerAsync().

Comment: So I should write out a RunWorkerAsync() and put all the control checking code in it? What do I put in the DoWork() to run the program? Just runProgram()?

Comment: Do you really need to use `BackgroundWorker` to check some empty text boxes? Check that in the main thread and let the worker do the lengthy routine.

Comment: And remove the `Try..Catch` block from the DoWork. Check/handle the errors in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: @HansPassant I removed the Try Catch from the backgroundworker and put the code for checking the text boxes in the execute button function. I have a problem in the cntrl.focus, launchProgream = False, the message box appears but never give focus back to the form so I can enter text in it

Comment: `CType(cntrl, TextBox).Text = ""` all Controls have a Text property. No need to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you check a single text box a time and show the message if its empty:

```vb
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    For Each cntrl As TextBox In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cntrl.Text) Then
            cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter value in all fields on form" & cntrl.Name.ToString())
            cntrl.Focus()
            Return
        Else
            cntrl.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End If
    Next

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Or maybe concatenate the names of the empty text boxes in the `For..Each` block if you really need to prompt the user this way:

```vb
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For Each cntrl As TextBox In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cntrl.Text) Then
            If sb.Length > 0 Then sb.Append(", ")
            sb.Append(cntrl.Name)
            cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Else
            cntrl.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End If
    Next

    If sb.Length > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter value in all fields on form" & sb.ToString())
        Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(a) String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Text)).FirstOrDefault?.Focus()
        Return
    End If

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Otherwise, run the worker.

Good luck.

Comment: @MaxineHammett No problem, Good luck.

Comment: For some more context, I had already answered this differently https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720697/832052

Comment: @djv loool Same OP. Just noticed that.

Comment: @JQSOFT your answer is good. There are multiple ways to solve a problem. It's just that I thought this problem was already solved :P

Comment: @JQSOFT no, we don't mark answers as dupes. Only questions. Enjoy the rep for the work you did.